# PLT-Scheme learning reference

Tags: scheme, racket, htdp

After having got through the two *Schemer* books, I'm about to embark on HtDP but also discovered the http://docs.plt-scheme.org/guide material.

The previously mentioned books are more particular to Scheme, it seems, and the latter being more geared towards PLT specific extensions (modules, require, bracket syntax, etc...). The online manual is excellent but I was hoping there might be a book form that I could purchase?

If not, I'm certainly grateful for the in-depth online manual - was just curious!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't believe so. The only other PLT-specific book that's in print right know (AFAIK) is the excellent ["Semantics Engineering with PLT Redex"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262062755), but I don't think that's what you're looking for. You might also be interested in Krishnamurthi's [Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation](http://www.plai.org).  Both of these are targeted at programming languages folks.

HTH

Comment: Cool, thank you John! The online manual isn't bad - it's really quite good, I just prefer having a book to read from...

Answer (score 1):

- [How to Design Worlds](http://world.cs.brown.edu/)
- [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org/)
- [Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/)

Comment: I appreciate the list but it wasn't what I was asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pdf version of the guide which might be easier for you to use than the html document:

http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/4.0.2/pdf/guide.pdf

I assume this is legit, feel free to edit my post if it isn't.